# How to deploy WCF service on IIS 6.0

Tags: wcf, iis-6, http-status-code-404, deployment

I have IIS 6.0 on Windows Server 2003.

I installed .NET 3.5 and 4 beta 2. "Normal" ASP things are working (perfect). But when I try to navigate to my service (`/myServer/MyService.svc`) I get a 404. Page not found.

To be exact, I got a 404 2 "Web service extension lockdown policy prevents this request."

I used `ServiceModelReg.exe /ia` to make sure that the extension I known and I checked the configuration using:

admin-Tools, iis, home-tab, configuration,  executable-box, and there:

Extension: .svc, path: `c:\windows\microsoft.net\framework\v4.0.210...`, verbs: all verbs.

So everything seems OK. But I still get a 404-2.

Comment: is it your choice / wish that .svc files get handled by .NET 4 already??

Answer (score 7):

Your "web service extension lockdown policy" is preventing the ASP.NET 4.0 ISAPI extension from processing your request. It happened to me, check it out:

```
C:\>cscript c:\WINDOWS\system32\iisext.vbs /ListFile
Microsoft (R) Windows Script Host Version 5.6
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation 1996-2001. All rights reserved.

Connecting to server ...Done.

Status / Extension Path
------------------------
0  C:\WINDOWS\system32\inetsrv\httpodbc.dll
0  C:\WINDOWS\system32\inetsrv\ssinc.dll
0  C:\WINDOWS\system32\inetsrv\asp.dll
1  C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll
0  *.exe
0  C:\WINDOWS\system32\inetsrv\httpext.dll
0  *.dll
1  C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll
1  C:\WINDOWS\system32\MQISE.DLL
0  C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll
```

Do you have a "0" next to the v4.0 aspnet_isapi.dll like I did? There's your problem. You need to enable it:

```
C:\>cscript c:\WINDOWS\system32\iisext.vbs /EnFile C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Frame
work64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll
Microsoft (R) Windows Script Host Version 5.6
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation 1996-2001. All rights reserved.

Connecting to server ...Done.
Enabling extension file complete.
```

For more info on the iisext.vbs tool: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/328419/

Comment: This was exactly my problem. I'm currently troubleshooting a problem on an old server and getting WCF working on Win2003/IIS6 took longer that I expected.

Answer (score 2):

Can you show us your server-side web.config (just the `<system.serviceModel>` section)? Where on your server does your service live?

When hosting in IIS, your service address is defined by:

- server name (or IP address)
- name of the virtual directory (plus any subdirectories under that) in which your *.svc file lives
- the *.svc file itself

So it would be something like:

```
http://YourServer/YourVirtualDirectory/MyService.svc
```

You don't seem to use a virtual directory in the path you mention - is your *.svc file really in the root of the web server, or did you forget to add the virtual directory to your path?

Answer (score 1):

The information in this blog post proved invaluable to getting this to work.

http://xamlcoder.com/blog/?p=7

I am not sure about IIS6 but I created a new website in IIS7 (I could not get things to work under a virtual directory but that is probably my lack of IIS knowledge)  I put my .svc file in the root directory and in ~/Services/

Everything started working great.

The blog mentioned that IIS should look in ~/Services/ automatically anytime a .svc file is served up but that was not working.  That is why I simply copied the .svc file to my website root.

Hope this helps.