# IIS 6 not able to pick the framework 4.0 dll when deployed

Tags: c#-4.0, iis-6

I have an service written in framework 4.0 and deployed in IIS 6, operating system 64 bit Windows Server 2003.

Steps done from me

```
1:Installed framework 4.0 of 64 bit
2 : C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319 aspnet_regiis –i
3: C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\ServiceModelReg.exe –i
4: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2009233/how-to-deploy-wcf-service-on-iis-6-0
```

The same code work fine when deployed in IIS 7, operating system Windows Server 2008

When I browse the url it shows the service working fine.

When I am consuming the service it throws an error tells invalid length here; it's trying to pick the framework 2.0 dll which is causing the problem
code which is causing the problem: `Encoding.Unicode.GetString(MachineKey.Decode)`

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that you selected the .NET 4.0 Framework in the ASP.NET tab of the virtual directory of your service:

[image]